# Making a navigation dropdown appear over a slider

Tags: css, wordpress

Having an issue with my WordPress theme. The navigation seems to sit behind the slider.
The theme is based off "Twenty Twelve". But it should be some CSS changes.

I'm not really sure on how to approach this and any feedback is much appreciated.

When I push the slider up (How I want it):

[image]

When the slider is pushed down:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `z-index` of your submenu higher then the `z-index` of your slider (`z-index: 100`).

Example:

```
.main-navigation li ul {
   display: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know about z-index. I changed it to 101 just to keep things easier to remember when i read it later

Comment: While you're learning about `z-index`, also make sure to learn about stacking orders in case you ever want to position things on top of other things in the future. Here's one website describing it: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/